# Are the distances of the kNN i.i.d?

Tags: machine-learning, confidence-interval, independence, descriptive-statistics

Imagine the set of i.i.d observations $D = \{x_i\}_{i=1}^N \subset X^n$.
Let the distance function $d \colon X^n \times X^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be used to find the $k$ nearest neighbors to the query $x_q$.
As a result we have the distances $d_1,\dots,d_k$.
My question is actually divided into two parts:

1) Is it incorrect to estimate a confidence interval on the distances $d_1,\dots,d_k$? Do they have to be i.i.d.?
2) Are the distances i.i.d?

PS: I am not sure what tags I should add to my question. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Minor notation question: you indicate that $\vec x_i \in X^n$ but the domain of $d$ is $X \times X$. Should the former be $X$ or the latter be $X^n \times X^n$?

Answer (score 2):

They don't have to be iid and yes you can definitely generate confidence intervals. In fact, they often are not iid. Think about the distances between houses in a large city. Are those distances independent of each other?

Google "Markov Random Fields" for some related topics and thoughts on how to make this more rigorous.